# Sandbox account posted to live gamecenter boards! Any way to delete score?

Tags: xcode, game-center

I was testing out an update to my app, and while logged into my gamecenter sandbox account on the device, ran my project on my iPhone. Foolishly, without thinking to check I was in sandbox mode, I ran the game with a cheat I enabled for testing purposes to skip to the end. Consequently, my sandbox account now has the highest score on the live GC leaderboards!

I was hoping there might be some backdoor way to delete my own score. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you can do is log into your iTunesConnect account, go to "Manage Your Applications" select your game, select "manage game center", then click on "Delete Test Data".

Comment: What I'm trying to do is delete my erroneous score from the live gamecenter servers, not the sandbox server. Sorry, my question rambled a bit!

Comment: There is probably no way to fix that. I've seen lots of games with many scores set to the highest integer. I assumed they were either mistakes or intentionally set that way on jail broken phones. Game Center needs another round of design improvements!

Comment: Thanks for that. That is kind of what I feared.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing a lot of GameCenter coding in recent weeks and the behavior you are expressing here appears as though you had the following conditions.  (I do not know of a fix other than opening up one of your precious Apple Developer trouble tickets to remove that score.)

1. You had an application in the live App Store with a version number X.Y.
2. You coded some new changes into the application using the same version number X.Y. and proceeded to debug the app using your sandbox account.  You scored a fantastic score through your code and it posted to the live Game Center.

Was this tied to the version number X.Y?  I believe you can control this situation by making certain that you changed this?  I'm just very curious here and hoping that I do not fall into the same issue in the next few months as we release our online playable game.  Thanks for any insight into your situation.